# Ignore mod_deflate for specific files or portions of code

Tags: php, apache

I'm using mod_deflate for php/html files.  I have some instances where this is causing some display problems for formatted code.  Is there anyway to ignore mod_deflate in certain instances?

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of display problems? `mod_deflate` has nothing to do with layout and should never modify any of your code. A HTML file transported using `mod_deflate`  should look 100% the same as a HTML file transported without compression. Can you show an example?

Comment: It doesn't preserve tabs and returns.  I'm using CodeMirror as an editor and it causes all the code to be on a single line, instead of preserving the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_deflate` should not remove tabs and returns. Its job is to compress and uncompress data with 0% modification.

I don't fully understand the situation, but my guess this is a Linux vs. Windows issue.

Maybe you are working with files that have only a Unix line break `\n` instead of a Windows line break `\r\n`, and CodeMirror isn't correctly getting that?

If this is not it, maybe add more information about how those files get from `mod_deflate` into your editor.

Comment: Ok I'm an idiot... I had compression turned on in an unexpected place.. thanks :p